# Canvas Drawing/Animation

Tags: javascript, beginner, animation, collision

I am trying to learn how to write good, clean, and efficient JavaScript. I consider myself a novice, at best, in JavaScript. Any comments are appreciated.

In an effort to become a better JavaScript programmer, I am trying to write a simple JavaScript animation using HTML5's new canvas element. Functionally speaking, when the canvas is clicked, a new circle (or Ball) is added to the canvas and begins moving to the lower right corner of the canvas. When the ball hits a wall or collides with another ball, the speed at which the x and y coordinates are moving is inverted.

Is it a good idea to be modifying the `this` object? For instance does the following pattern make sense?

```
function Point(I) {
    this.x = I.x;
    this.y = I.y;
    this.z = I.z;
    return this;
}
```

Is there any reason why I shouldn't be sending a object and pulling variables off of the input object? I like the syntax for creation, but are there any problems with this pattern?

```
new Point({
    x: 10,
    y: 30
});
new Point({
    x: 50,
    y: 25
    z: 3
});
```

**Full Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ball Collision</title>
<script src="js/modernizr-1.7.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        //"use strict";

        // Source: http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/canvas/notearsgame/
        Number.prototype.clamp = function(min, max) {
            return Math.min(Math.max(this, min), max);
        };


        if (Modernizr.canvas) {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


            canvas.width = 500;
            canvas.height = 375;
            canvas.style.border = "3px solid red";

            function Point(I) {
                console.log("Point created");
                this.x = I.x;
                this.y = I.y;
                this.z = I.z;
                return this;
            }

            function Ball(I) {
                console.log("Ball created");

                var SPEED_LIMIT = 10;

                this.point = new Point(I.point);
                this.radius = (I.radius > 10 ? I.radius : 10);
                this.color = I.color;
                this.speed = new Point(I.speed);
                this.collision = false;
                this.mass = I.mass || 1;

                this.draw = function() {
                    this.point.x = this.point.x.clamp(0 + this.radius, canvas.width - this.radius);
                    this.point.y = this.point.y.clamp(0 + this.radius, canvas.height - this.radius);
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(this.point.x, this.point.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
                    ctx.fill();
                };

                this.update = function() {
                    this.clear();

                    if ( this.point.x <= this.radius || this.point.x >= (canvas.width - this.radius)) {
                        this.speed.x *= -1;
                    }

                    if ( this.point.y <= this.radius || this.point.y >= (canvas.height - this.radius)) {
                        this.speed.y *= -1;
                    }

                    if ( this.speed.x > SPEED_LIMIT ) {
                        this.speed.x = SPEED_LIMIT;
                    }
                    if ( this.speed.x < SPEED_LIMIT * -1 ) {
                        this.speed.x = SPEED_LIMIT * -1;
                    }
                    if ( this.speed.y > SPEED_LIMIT ) {
                        this.speed.y = SPEED_LIMIT;
                    }
                    if ( this.speed.y < SPEED_LIMIT * -1 ) {
                        this.speed.y = SPEED_LIMIT * -1;
                    }

                    this.point.x += this.speed.x;
                    this.point.y += this.speed.y;
                };

                this.clear = function() {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(this.point.x - 1, this.point.y - 1, this.radius + 2, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
                    ctx.fill();
                };

                return this;
            }

            var balls = [];

            function handleCollisions() {
                function collide(ball1, ball2) {
                    ball1.speed.x *= -1;
                    ball2.speed.x *= -1;
                    ball1.speed.y *= -1;
                    ball2.speed.y *= -1;
                }


                function checkCollisions() {
                    var i, j, a, b;

                    for ( i = 0; i < balls.length; i++ ) {
                        for ( j = i+1; j < balls.length; j++ ) {
                            a = balls[i];
                            b = balls[j];

                            var dx = Math.abs(a.point.x - b.point.x);
                            var dy = Math.abs(a.point.y - b.point.y);
                            var d = (dx*dx)+(dy*dy);
                            var r = (a.radius + b.radius) * (a.radius + b.radius);

                            if ( d < r && ( !a.collision || !b.collision ) ) {
                                a.collision = true;
                                b.collision = true;
                                collide(a, b);
                            } else if ( d > r ) {
                                a.collision = false;
                                b.collision = false;
                            }                           
                        }
                    }
                }

                checkCollisions();
            }

            function update() {
                balls.forEach(function(ball) {
                    ball.update();
                });

                handleCollisions();
            }

            function draw() {
                balls.forEach(function(ball) {
                    ball.draw();
                });
            }

            var FPS = 30;
            var loop = setInterval( function() {
                update();
                draw();
            }, 1000/FPS);

            canvas.onclick = function(e) {              
                var radiusAndMass = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
                var speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

                balls.push(new Ball({
                    point: {
                        //x: Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width),
                        //y: Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height),
                        x: e.offsetX,
                        y: e.offsetY
                    },
                    color: "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16),
                    radius: radiusAndMass,
                    mass: radiusAndMass,
                    speed: {
                        x: speed,
                        y: speed
                    }
                }));
            };


            document.getElementById('canvas-container').appendChild(canvas);
        }
    };
</script>   
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="canvas-container">

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

> Is it a good idea to be modifying the this object? For instance does the following pattern make sense?
>
> ```
> function Point(I) {
>     this.x = I.x;
>     this.y = I.y;
>     this.z = I.z;
>     return this;
> }
> ```

Yes and no. Modifying `this` is normal in a constructor function, but what you're doing here is unusual. Something like this would be more common:

```
function Point(x, y, z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}
```

With this parameter list, it's very clear what we are passing in (3D coordinates); with just `I`, it's not clear unless we read the code in the constructor. Not a huge deal here, but with `Ball`, we have no clue what `I` is supposed to contain unless we read the entire constructor.

There's no reason to `return this`; you're invoking it with `new`, and the result of that expression will be the constructed object. The function doesn't need to return anything.

> Is there any reason why I shouldn't be sending a object and pulling variables off of the input object? I like the syntax for creation, but are there any problems with this pattern?

There's nothing *wrong* with it, but since your `Point` doesn't do anything (i.e. it has no function properties, only `x`, `y` and `z`) you might as well forget about `Point` and just use object literals if you're passing object literals to the `Point` constructor anyway. In other words, you're creating an object literal and then copying all of its properties into something that happens to be called a "Point" but aside from that has the exact same capabilities as the object you passed into the constructor. Why do that extra step?

---

With `Ball`, you should attach function properties to `Ball.prototype` rather than assign them inside of the constructor. There is no reason for each `Ball` object to have its own separate set of function properties, and doing so incurs extra overhead. In other words, with your code `someBall.draw != anotherBall.draw`, but it would be much more efficient if all balls reference the same `draw` function property.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there are any strong reasons towards any of the approaches (object vs values), but I will list out all the advantages/disadvantages of both ways so that you'll choose what seems better for you:

#### Passing in an object of the structure you're describing (`function Point(I)`)

**[+]** creating new instances from older instances or compatible objects (anything with x, y and z) is trivial: `new Point(oldPoint)` or `new Point(thingThatQuaksLikeAPoint)`*

**[-]** creating new instances from just numbers becomes tedious and annoying (and creates garbage (which MAY be an issue in some cases (really bad for number crunching/real time apps on slow hardware/bad JS implementations))). `new Point({ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 })` vs `new Point(1, 2, 3)`
Or, take the following function for instance:

```
function add(P1, P2) {
    var newX = P1.x + P2.x;
    var newY = P1.y + P2.y;
    var newZ = P1.z + P2.z;

    return new Point({ x: newX, y: newY, z: newZ });
    
    // why do I have to wrap my numbers it in an object?!? :(
    // new Point(newX, newY, newZ); is so much more to the point!
}
```

**[-]** the constructor has access to more than it needs to - it's nice in general to set fences in your app and guarantee that some boundaries are not crossed. If you pass in a full object then by mistake or temptation you might modify the state of the passed object (which leads to very subtle bugs)

#### Passing in individual components (`function Point(x, y, z)`)

**[+]** creating new instances from numbers is trivial, sweet short and to the point - it's as easy as `new Point(1, 2, 3)`

**[-]** if calling with other Points then it will become tedious to extract x, y and z every time `new Point(otherPoint.x, otherPoint.y, otherPoint.z)` vs `new Point(otherPoint)`

### So why not support both ways?!

```
function Point(x, y, z) {
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        // we got only one argument - it's a Point!
        var that = x; // just aliasing
        this.x = that.x;
        this.y = that.y;
        this.z = that.z;
    } else {
        // let's presume there can be only these 2 cases
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

This might be a bit slower, but it's worth it IMO - it makes creating points a breeze ;)

---

I do see a couple of bits of code which could be improved in the sample that you pasted. If you're looking to write nice, clean JS then consider looking up how the *prototype* works. Also learn why *requestAnimationFrame* is much nicer than *setTimeout* (which is nicer than *setInterval*). Also, you may use `rgb(1, 2, 3)` as a valid color instead of `#010203`.

* See [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)

Answer (score 2):

I think that pattern is fine. It has the advantage that you have "named arguments", which is very readable and can be useful if you call the some function/constructor with different sets of arguments.

The only thing I'd suggest is to use another name for the parameter, because capital letters are generally used for constructor functions:

```
function Point(p) {
    this.x = p.x;
    this.y = p.y;
    this.z = p.z;
    return this;
}
```